# Как расположить кнопку (textView) в самом низу экрана?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Есть несколько кнопок Linearlayout по центру (xml), и я хочу добавить одну textView, чтобы она располагалась в самом низу экрана, чтобы другие элементы не перетаскивались от этого вверх и не меняли свое местоположение впринципе.
Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что вам нужно, но при таком раскладе `textView2` будет всегда оставаться снизу.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_av_2"
                style="?attr/myCardViewStyle"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detail_1"
                        style="@style/textMainSchedule"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и незамысловатый вариант:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

            //ваши другие view

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1" //чтобы при увеличении числа строк TV не увеличивался в размерах
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```